How to solve argument is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'?
Main.ts
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify';
import * as components from 'vuetify/components';
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives';

const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
});

app.use(vuetify);
app.mount('#app');

Button.vue
<v-btn rounded color="#000" variant="outlined" @click="()=>{}">Download</v-btn>

I am getting an error while I run npm run build called Argument of type '{ rounded: boolean; color: string; variant: string; onClick: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
how do we solve this?

Please share your tsconfig.json file

{   "compilerOptions": {     "types": ["vite/client"],     "target": "esnext",     "module": "esnext",     "paths": {       "@/*": [         "./src/*" // set path @/* as alias of src/*       ]     },   },   "files": [],   "references": [     {       "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"     },     {       "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"     }   ] }
@BoussadjraBrahim

I think you missed to add vuetify types to the tsconfig.json :
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "types": [
            "vite/client",
             "vuetify"
        ],
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "esnext",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": [
                "./src/*"
            ]
        },
    },
    "files": [],
    "references": [
        {
            "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
        },
        {
            "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
        }
    ]
}


Still not working

@RohanJayaraj can you provide a minimal repro in stackblitz?
